# Получить зависимости из родительского pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Нужно достать зависимости из parent pom.xml и сохранить в List.
В коде прописывается путь до pom.xml, который указан в ниже:

Основной pom.xml:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>TestGroubId</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>TestVersion</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>TestGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>backend</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
    <module>test</module>
  </modules>
```

Comment: Вы пишите плагин к мавену или это просто java приложение?

Comment: java приложение. Необходимо получить dependency driver для базы данных, как раз dependency прописаны в родительском pom.xml

Comment: Хочется получить путь к jar файлу с драйвером? Это очень странный подход. Почему бы не добавить эту зависимость в сам проект?

Comment: Есть метод, который определяет подгрузку нужного драйвера с удаленного репозитория, в зависимости от выбранной БД. В методе прописан путь до pom.xml-наследника, а от него нужно уже дойти до родительского pom и забрать зависимости.

Comment: Придется парсить xml в ручную. Находить тег родителя и резолвить его. Затем парсить xml родителя. Находить зависимость с драйвером (непонятно как,  она от других зависимостей не отличается) и загружать. Очень странный подход. Можно попробовать переиспользовать код из самого мавена, но это дофига разбиратся что там и как. Советую придумать что-нибудь другое.